# Copy range to last row and paste in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need vba code to copy everything starting from A5, everything to the right of it and down to the last row in one workbook and paste it into another Workbook, starting at A5.

This is the code that I have so far, but it's not working.

```
Windows("Month By Month Income Statment 10.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Month By Month Income Statmen-A").Select
Range("A5").Select

Dim EC As Long
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long
X = Range("A5").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
EC = Range("A5").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, X).Column

Range("A5" & EC).Select
Selection.Copy

Windows("RPG - Apr Mnth acs by co.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("010 - RPL").Select
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you had another question to answer, so I had a go at this one too.

I know it wasn't in your original request, but I've added a section that clears the contents of the "RPG" file first (Only from row 5 downwards), so that you won't run in to any problems. This way you will always have a blank page to paste your new data in to and you'll never have data left over from last time if your new data is smaller than your old data. If you don't need this bit feel free to leave it out.

```
Sub Get_New_Data_From_Other_Workbook()
'
' This macro will copy data from a .xlsx file and paste it back into the .xlsm file
' Any contents in the .xlsm file will first be deleted

    ' Clear the existing contents of the destination sheet
    Windows("RPG - Apr Mnth acs by co.xlsm").Activate                   ' Make sure the RPG file is selected
    Sheets("010 - RPL").Select                                          ' Select the required sheet
    Range("A5").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select        ' From A5, select every cell until the end of the page (up to where the data stops)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents                                             ' Delete contents
    Range("A1").Select                                                  ' Select A1 for presentation purposes

    ' Go to the correct sheet of the other workbook and copy the data
    Windows("Month By Month Income Statement 10.xlsx").Activate         ' Select the other workbook
    Sheets("Month By Month Income Statmen-A").Select                    ' Select the sheet with the data on
    Range("A5").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select        ' From A5, select every cell until the end of the page (up to where the data stops)
    Selection.Copy                                                      ' Copy the data

    ' Come back to the macro workbook and paste the data in A5 of the required sheet
    Windows("RPG - Apr Mnth acs by co.xlsm").Activate                   ' Select the RPG file
    Sheets("010 - RPL").Select                                          ' Select the required sheet
    Range("A5").Select                                                  ' Select cell A5
    ActiveSheet.Paste                                                   ' Paste the data
    Range("A1").Select                                                  ' Select A1 for presentation purposes

End Sub
```

Comment: I am new to this site. How do I accept the solution? I tried to click on the above arrow and received a notice telling that anyone with less than 15 reputation, the site will accept my score, but it will not be shown on this thread.

Comment: Here is a helpful link that can hopefully explain how to do this and the benefits of doing so :) 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work